# No se reconoce Javascript propio

Tags: php, javascript, html, xampp

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en XAMPP con PHP y JS.

Tengo las carpetas acomodadas en este orden:

1) `app/asset/css` (Guardo los archivos css, 'bootstrap' y mi principal)

2) `app/asset/dist` (Guardo los archivos js, 'bootstrap', 'jquery' y mi principal 'main.min.js')

3) `app/asset/resources` (Guardo los archivos de imágenes,iconos,etc)

4) `app/module/index` (Guardo los módulos php como 'footer','head',(principales))

5) `app/module/juego` (Guardo los módulos php básicos del juego)

6) `app/index.php` (Archivo principal que se enlaza todo el contenido)

7) el resto no creo que importen porque son carpetas de Sass y el Js que minifico con Gulp.

**Ahora, ¿Cúal es mi problema?**

Cuando quiero comprobar si se enlazo bien mi archivo 'main.min.js' al index.php no me retorna información de este, ni tampoco da un mensaje de error.

Los únicos archivos que responden son los de `bootstrap.min.js` y `jquery.min.js` ya que estoy ocupando sus funcionalidades.

Pero del `main.min.js` no recibo ninguna respuesta por consola.

**¿Cómo lo estoy enlazando?**

Mi archivo index.php es así:

```
   <?php

   require 'module/index/head.php';

   require 'module/index/header.php';

   require 'module/index/conn.php';

   ?>



    <h1 id="tituloPrincipal" class="text-center">Titulo de Proyecto</h1>


    <div id="cajaPrincipal">        


    <?php

    require 'module/juego/menu.php';

    require 'module/juego/pantallaMenu.php';

    ?>

    </div>



    <?php

    require 'module/index/footer.php';

    ?>
```

**¿Cómo esta escrito el `Footer`?**

```
   <script src="asset/dist/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

   <script src="asset/dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <script scr="asset/dist/main.min.js"></script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

**¿Cúal es el error?**

La verdad que desconozco que pueda ser... como les digo, me toma los otros archivos Javascript que ocupa bootstrap salvando el mio 'main.min.js'.

Si reviso el código fuente me muestra que mi archivo esta escrito en el `index.php` (aunque no me reconozca los console.log que le envió), la diferencia es que los otros dos archivos (de bootstrap) resaltan como vínculo menos el mio.

Comment: ¿Qué error te arroja?

Comment: Ninguno la verdad..Le mando un console.log('Hola') pero no me retorna nada.

Comment: El unico error que me sale en consola es de boostrap que requiere theter.

AGREGO:

Tambien probe el tema de la cache, CTRL + F5, tambien la borre manualmente.

Comment: No entiendo qué es lo que intentas realizar con `console.log`, ¿Verificar que JavaScript está corriendo en Bootstrap?

Comment: No.. lo que intento hacer es mandar un console.log de mi archivo principal para poder empezar a enlazar el Javascript con el HTML, si no es capas de retornarme el log, no veo sentido de seguir avanzando.. Pero el navegador solo me reconoce los archivos javascript de bootstrap y jquery, no el mio.

Comment: Te recomendaría que redactes mejor tu pregunta y especifiques a detalle que es lo que quieres hacer, debido a que sigo sin entender.

Comment: Ahí lo Re-Edite, pero al menos para mi esta claro el mensaje.

El Archivo Index.php me reconoce los archivos Javascript de Bootstrap y Jquery.

El Archivo Index.php NO me reconoce el archivo Javascript mio que contiene un console.log.

Los Archivos Javascript de Bootstrap funcionan de manera correcta como estan enlazados.

El Archivo Javascript Mio esta enlazado de igual manera pero no responde mis peticiones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de analizar minuciosamente las líneas donde importas los `scripts` (tuve que leerlas por lo menos 5 veces) encontré tu error:

```
<script scr="asset/dist/main.min.js"></script>
```

El atributo es `src` y no `scr` por lo cual la línea debe quedar así:

```
<script src="asset/dist/main.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: son esos errores tontos de novato.. muchísimas muchísimas gracias enserio :) ! me pase la tarde tratando de ver porque no me lo tomaba que termine aprendiendo a gulp para minificar jaja..del cansancio ya no veía donde estaba el error.

Comment: Suele suceder jejeje acabo de leer en tu perfil que eres amante de **JavaScript**, yo igual !! pásate algún día por el [chat], saludos !

Comment: Ahi estare! +10

Comment: Camilo!..Ahora puedo dejar puntuación, así que gracias por hacerme dar cuenta de este error y ayudarme en el de los input con removeEventListener.